# Add integer to another integer in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can I add an integer to another integer in vb.net?

This is what I need to do:

Given integer: 2187  -> 
Converted integer: 2018

I need to add a 0 in between the first and second number, and drop the last digit. This will give me the year.

Here is the code that I have:

```
Protected Function GetYear(ByVal term As Integer) As Integer

    Dim termYear As String = Convert.ToString(term)

    termYear.Substring(0, 2)
    termYear.Insert(1, "0")

    Dim convertedYear As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(termYear.ToString, convertedYear)

    convertedYear = convertedYear / 10

    Return convertedYear

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general strings are immutable. So you'd have to create a new string out of the addition of substrings. Check this possible solution.

```
Function GetYear(ByVal term As Integer) As Integer

    Dim termYear As String = Convert.ToString(term, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

    Dim result As String = termYear.Substring(0, 1) + "0" + termYear.Substring(1, 2)

    Return Int32.Parse(result)

End Function
```

Comment: As [Convert.ToString(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_) uses the formatting conventions of the current thread culture, it would be safest to use `Convert.ToString(term, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to avoid a possible thousands separator getting in there.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, when you do any changes with one of their method, you need to get the returned string.

```
termYear = termYear.Insert(1, "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

This question deserves a math based solution.  The below code specifies the zero insertion point relative to the number's right side instead of the left as stated in the problem statement.  So for a 4 digit number the insertion point is 3 versus 2.  It also allows you to change the insertion point.

```
Private Function GetYear(ByVal term As Integer, Optional zeroDigitPosition As Integer = 3) As Integer
    If zeroDigitPosition > 0 Then
        Dim divisor As Integer = 1
        For i As Integer = 1 To zeroDigitPosition - 1
            divisor *= 10
        Next
        Dim ret As Integer = term \ 10 ' drop one's place digit, remaining digits shift to right
        Dim rightShiftedDigits As Integer = ret Mod divisor
        Dim remainder As Integer = Math.DivRem(ret, divisor, rightShiftedDigits)
        ' shift the remainder to the left by divisor * 10 
        ' (remember first right shift invplved \ 10) and add
        ' rightShiftedDigits to yield result
        Return (remainder * divisor * 10) + rightShiftedDigits
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("zeroDigitPosition must be greater then zero")
    End If
End Function
```